# Angular 2 - How to make a service available at app module level

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble calling a function inside of a service I thought is being made available globally. I have created a service called `SavedNotificationService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SavedNotificationService {

    private showSavedNotification = false;

    show(): void {
        this.showSavedNotification = true;
    }

    hide(): void {
        this.showSavedNotification = false;
    }

}
```

And I have imported it in app.module.ts:

```
import { SavedNotificationService } from "./saved-notification.service";
@NgModule({
providers: [SavedNotificationService]
})
```

But when I want to call a function inside the service it says it can't find it. Although I have made the service available at app.module do I still have to import it on the component I wish to use it? (Like the below example)

```
@Component({
  providers: [SavedNotificationService]
})
```

Comment: you have to import it like `import { SavedNotificationService } from "./saved-notification.service";`. You shouldnt set as provider

Comment: If you add it to `providers` at a component, you'll get a different instance for this component (and children). If you don't want that, don't add it to providers.

Comment: @suraj I have to do that on the actual component I want to use it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import it and then inject it to your component as a dependency via the constructor.

Something like this:

```
import { ExampleService } from '....' // where your services are.

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'example-component',
    templateUrl: 'example-component.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _exampleService: ExampleService) { 
    }
```

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) you can read more about injecting services and working with them.

P.S: If you register your service at a global scope(AppModule) you will be able to inject it everywhere in your app. You can also register your service at a given Module where the scope of injection will be different.(You should be careful with that, because you can end with different instances of the service at a given time.)

Comment: Oh I thought the benefit of importing the service at app.module level was so that you can avoid having to do the import on every single component you need to use it on. So in any event you always have to do import on every single component?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward, no. You have to import the service and inject it everywhere you want to use it. By putting in the providers in the AppModule you are basically saying that you can inject it everywhere in your app(every component that is).

Comment: Ah ok so if you put it into the providers at app.module that will save you from having to declare the provider at the component level but you will still have to do the import?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward, exactly. The import + the injection in the constructor. As I said in my answer, you can have different scopes of the services and in your case it's better to just put them in the providers array of the AppModule. After doing that you can inject the service in the constructor of any component and have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

Once you declare service in module their is no need to re declare in your component...just import it in your component and init it in your constructor as

```
import { SavedNotificationService } from "./saved-notification.service";
@Component({
})
export class xyz{

service;

constructor(service:SavedNotificationService)
{

}
//call the method using this instance
service.show();

}
```